# Setting date limits inside geom_boxplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have one question about how `geom_boxplot` works. First I am using date type data and try not to plot all my data, only a part.

First I load my packages

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(quantmod)
```

I am using getSymbols to get my data

```
yahoo <- getSymbols(auto.assign = F,Symbols = "QQQ")
chartSeries(yahoo,subset = "last 3 month")
```

I shape my data to use it in ggplot

```
df <- yahoo %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  rename("time" = "rowname") %>% 
  mutate(time = as.Date(time))
```

I set my date limits

```
l <- c(df$time[10],df$time[100])
```

Then I try to plot it

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = time,
                   lower  = QQQ.Close,
                   upper  = QQQ.Open,
                   ymin   = QQQ.Low,
                   ymax   = QQQ.High,
                   middle = QQQ.Open),
               stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_date(limits = l)
```

and I get error:

> ```
> Error in if (df$xmin[i] >= df$xmax[i - 1]) { : 
>   valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario
> ```

I try a different way:

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = time,
                   lower  = QQQ.Close,
                   upper  = QQQ.Open,
                   ymin   = QQQ.Low,
                   ymax   = QQQ.High,
                   middle = QQQ.Open),
               stat = "identity") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = l)
```

The second way works but my question is: why the first plot give me error? If I try with different geom i can use the `scale_x_date limits` parameter. for example:

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = time,
                y = QQQ.Adjusted)) +
  scale_x_date(limits = l)
```

Why this doesn't work with the first plot?

Comment: Not sure exactly why (hence posting this as a comment rather than an answer), but I found your error message in the code for [`position_dodge2`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/position-dodge2.r), which is the default position for `geom_boxplot`. Add `position = "dodge"`, to `geom_boxplot()`, and your first way works for me without any error. (I'm on R 3.4.3, ggplot2 3.0.0) Perhaps something in `position_dodge2` doesn't work well with the `Date` class when you choose `stat = "identity"` for boxplot...

Comment: It seem that the problem is "position_dodge2" as you say @Z.lin . I try the same code in ggplot2 ‘2.2.1’ where "position_dodge" is used by default and it works. I'm not sure if this is a bug or this is the way ir should work. Thanks.